# How to register custom TypeAdapter or JsonDeserializer with Gson in Retrofit?

Tags: java, gson, retrofit, retrofit2, json-deserialization

I am using Retrofit in my project and I need some custom deserialization with some of the responses that the API I use returns.

Just for an example: I receive JSON like:

```
{ "status": "7 rows processed" }
```

*( will be "0 rows processed" if request failed )*

and I need to deserialize to an object like:

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public static class Result {
    private final boolean success;
}
```

I have created custom deserializer:

```
public class ResultDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Result> {
    @Override
    public Result deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        return new Result( ! json.getAsJsonObject().get("status").getAsString().startsWith("0"));
    }
}
```

and I am able to test it works when I register it like:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Result.class, new ResultDeserializer()).create();
```

*NOTE: this question is meant to be canonical/Q&A one and a inspired by the diffulty for me to find this when I need this information once in a year. So if the example seems to be artificial and stupid it is just because it should be simple. Hope this helps others also*

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to register customized `Gson` when building the `Retrofit` client. So after customizing `Gson` with custom `JsonDeserializer` like in question:

```
Gson customGson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Result.class, new ResultDeserializer())
    .create();
```

it is needed to register this `Gson` instance with `Retrofit` in building phase with help of `GsonConverterFactory`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/rest/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(customGson))
        .build();
```